# Creating an multidimensional Array from string (hierarchical data)

Tags: javascript

I have an Array with this kind of values:

```
val = [ ['L-2-4-1','john','bla1'],
      ['L-1-1-26','bohn','bla2'],
      ['L-2-1','cohn','bla3'],
      ['L-1-1-05','rohn','bla4'],
      ['L-1-1','gohn','bla5']
      ['L-2-3-1','zohn','bla-finally'] ];
```

The number-sequence is always unique and "0" is never used.
What I'm trying to get would be something like this:

```
ser = [ [undefined],
      [ [undefined],[ ['gohn'],['bla5'] ], [undefined], ... , [ ['bohn'], ['blah2'] ] ],
      ...
      ];
```

The purpose is to be able to access the data like this:

```
ser[2][4][1][0]; // Array('john','bla1')
ser[1][1][0]; // Array('gohn','bla5')
ser[1][1][26][0]; // Array('bohn','bla2')
```

and also to loop through all elements.. for instance:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= ser[1][1].length; i++){ //code }
```

The main problem I have is that I was not able to set the variables the same way I intend to read them. Because this does NOT work, since I need to declare all arrays separately as arrays (right?)

```
var ser[1][1][26][0] = ['john','bla1']; // Nop;
```

I don't know the maximum depth of the tree

Trying to build the arrays from "inside out" or from "right to left" -however it is best described- I always end up overwriting previously set array elements.

Maybe the whole idea is too complicated (or at least not ideal) for the purpose? What would you suggest? I have the feeling I´m trying to do the right thing but the wrong way... Something like organizing marbles on a glass surface. Everything keeps moving around...

Comment: Diodeus is right about by pointing out that the real problem is the data representation. That's why I +1ed his/her answer. But ckolz provided a solution nonetheless so I'll accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short and sweet:

```
var i, j, t, final = [];

for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  t = val[i][0].split('-');
  for (j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
     t[j] = parseInt(t[j], 10) || 0;
  }
  final[t[1]] = final[t[1]] || [];
  final[t[1]][t[2]] = final[t[1]][t[2]] || [];
  final[t[1]][t[2]][t[3]] = final[t[1]][t[2]][t[3]] || [];
  final[t[1]][t[2]][t[3]][t[4]] = final[t[1]][t[2]][t[3]][t[4]] || [];
  final[t[1]][t[2]][t[3]][t[4]].push(val[i].slice(1));
}
```

`final` now has the correct data as you specified...

however, you might want to consider using objects instead of arrays (change all [] to {}) as the random insertion points in arrays lead to series of empty (null) values, the only caveat would be that you'd have to use a `for (var key in obj)` style loop...

hope this helps -ck

**IF YOU NEED DYNAMIC DEPTH**

```
var i, j, t, o, depth = 4, final = [];

for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  t = val[i][0].split('-');
  o = final;
  for (j = 1; j <= depth; j++) {
     t[j] = parseInt(t[j], 10) || 0;
     o[t[j]] = o[t[j]] || [];
     o = o[t[j]];
  }
  o.push(val[i].slice(1));
}
```

now `depth` is the constant at which the data is stored missing or unparsable "keys" or "indices" depending on how you want to think of them, default to `0`

enjoy -ck

Comment: Short and sweet, indeed! The only shortcoming I am seeing is that it works for a maximum of 4 levels deep. I think my dataset has up to 9 levels somewhere... Do you know of any way to make this dynamic? I'll test your code on the complete dataset. You are right about the object. I'll test that, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered representing your data in JSON?

It allows for complex structures that are otherwise too confusing to keep in your head. It's like XML meets JavaScript arrays. Rather self-describing and easy to follow. You can read the lengths and sizes of objects easily and it's quite fast. You can use values instead of array positions and re-think the structure of your data.

http://json.org/example.html

Here is a record in JSON:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
},
```

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html

Comment: Thanks, Diodeus. I have tried to solve this mess also with objects and Json. As you suggested, my problems probably are caused mainly because of the structure of the data. I'll keep JSON in mind if I'm allowed to touch the data structure.